# css menu :after selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Hi I need some help with this.  The design calls for a vertical line separator in between each menu item, but only when they are not active.  I need to remove the left border from the a for the #current a (already done) as well as the next a.  Thoughts?

[image: menu]

```
#topmenu ul {margin: 0 0 7px 0; width: 100%;padding: 0;}
#topmenu li {list-style: none;display: inline;margin: 0 0px;padding:15px 10px 15px 0px;
line-height:15px;text-align:center;}
#topmenu a:link, #topmenu a {color: #ffffff;text-decoration: none;margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
font-weight:normal;padding: 0px 5px 0px 14px;
border-left-color:#fff; border-left-style:solid;border-left-width:1px;}
#topmenu ul li.item82 a, #topmenu #current  {border:none;}
#topmenu #current:after {border:none;}
#topmenu a:hover{color: #EFEFEF;}
#topmenu a:active{color: #EFEFEF;}
#topmenu #current{color: #EFEFEF;background-color:#19bcb9;-moz-border-radius-topright:4px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft:4px;
border-top-left-radius: 4px;border-top-right-radius: 4px; 
-webkit-border-top-right-radius:4px;-webkit-border-top-left-radius:4px;}

<ul class="menu">
<li class="item82"><a href="/about.html"><span>About Us</span></a></li>
<li class="item62"><a href="/our-philosophy.html"><span>Our Philosophy</span></a></li>
<li class="active item54" id="current"><a href="/services.html"><span>Services</span></a></li>
<li class="item74"><a href="/soutions.html"><span>Soutions</span></a></li>
<li class="item68"><a href="/workshops.html"><span>Workshops</span></a></li>
<li class="item75"><a href="/whats-new.html"><span>What's New</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Just to be clear I need to select the li a link AFTER li#current, not just the li.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adjacent sibling selector + will work. You will, though in this case, have to apply it to the child anchor element:

```
#topmenu #current a, #topmenu #current + li a {
    border-left-color: transparent ;
}
```

Instead of setting the border to none - try setting the color to 'transparent', so that the alignment of the layout isn't altered.

Answer (score 1):

try

`#topmenu #current:after + li {border:none;}`

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors

Comment: I tried this with + li and + li a and it actually added the border back in.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the handy-dandy css adjacent selector. Check it out at

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors

I think for yours you want

```
#topmenu #current + a{
border:none
}
```

though if you're already using javascript to add the #current ID it wouldnt be that hard to just add a .noborder class either.

Comment: I tried it unfortunately it didn't work.  I need to select the a in the li after li#current.